# HTML with CSS on Flutter

Tags: html, css, android-studio, flutter, dart

There are several html files and one css file that is used from all the html. I used the library flutter_html and the html files are being displayed normally but without css.

Is there a way to "import" the css file as it is without converting it to `Dart`?

Below is part of the css file. It's very simple. If it cannot be imported what is the best way to translate it to `Dart` code?

```
body {... margin-right:20; margin-bottom: 3 ...}

table {... margin-bottom: 3}

h1 {...}

h2 {font-family: 'palatino linotype'...}

h3 {...}

p:first-letter {...}

body {...}
```

Comment: Hope it can help https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/tree/master/example#how-to-use

Comment: @HantsanialaEléo so much time has passed but I think I solved by embedding the css directly into the webview concatenated with the html string. Thank you very though.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_html_css) library it can identify css as well

and then you can use your css as inline style

```
String htmlContent =
   """
   <p>This has no font size css property, but global style will be applied</p>
   <a style='color: orange;'>The inline color for this is orange, but it will 
   get overridden by global style defined below</a>
   """;
HTML.toTextSpan(
      context,
      htmlContent,
      overrideStyle: {
        "p": TextStyle(fontSize: 17.3),
        "a": TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        // specify any tag not just the supported ones,
        // and apply TextStyles to them and/override them
      },
    );
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.